# How do you reload .so files (dynamic libraries) in Linux?

Tags: linux, libraries, shared-library

I don't remember the command anymore, but in basically every Linux distro there's a command for reloading .so files and other libraries. How's it called?

It's something similar to `ld` I think. I tried `ldconfig` but it didn't help either.

Update:

I installed a library and a program is not picking up it's there.

**UPDATE 2**

I compiled the library and it installed it itself where required under /usr/local/lib I think?
I think `ldd program` doesn't contain the library, but I forgot to grep it...
I am getting the same as before installing the library: failed init

Comment: What's your use case? Why do you need to "reload `.so` files (which are shared libraries)?

Comment: The only command that comes to mind is `ldconfig`. What do you mean by "_it didn't help_"? What problem are you trying to resolve? What happened when you ran `ldconfig`? What didn't happen that you would have expected? Were there any error messages?

Comment: Please check the updated question.

Comment: Where did you install the library *to*? `ldconfig` will only search specific locations by default. What is the error message from the program? What is the output of `ldd path/to/program`?

Comment: Technically, ldconfig doesn't "reload" the libraries; it rebuilds the cache and updates links.  My guess would be your target library either is not in the ldconfig search path, or it is the wrong version for the executable you are attempting to use.  output from ldd probably would help.

Comment: What program are you trying to run, and what error message are you getting? Did you install it via your distribution's package manager or as a binary you downloaded from somewhere?

Comment: @Shadur I pulled the library from GitHub and compiled it myself

Comment: Then it was probably installed into `/usr/local/lib/` if it was installed at all, and I once again reiterate that you're probably better off using your distro's package manager if that's even *remotely* an option.

Comment: @Shadur apparently not an option, since the packages in the package managers are outdated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the file `/etc/ld.so.conf` (and the associated directory of files under `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`, if any). It should list the directory into which you've placed your library. Then run `ldconfig` to rebuild the cache of library filenames.

Comment: `ld.so.conf` seems to just include the contents of `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*`.The contents of `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` seem to show the libraries location, don't quite see how that is helpful, but `ldconfig` kinda sorta did the job I guess?

Comment: @SirMuffington "_sorta did the job_" - I'm puzzled. Either it worked or it didn't. What's your hesitancy?

Comment: I messed around a bit and something worked, but I'm not sure what.